# alertBox doesn't display when ticking checkbox

Tags: jquery

I can't see any error in my code. However, the Alertbox doesn't display when checkbox is ticking.

Is there anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function(){

              if($("#checkkBoxId").attr("checked"))
                        {
                            alert("Checked");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("Unchecked");
                        }

    });


    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p><input id="checkkBoxId" type="checkbox">Enable</p>
    </body>
```

Comment: Do you really need to use an ancient version of jQuery? 1.6.4 is recent and in this version you can use `.prop()` which is faster and more comfortable for things like getting the check state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to bind the click event on the checkbox like

```
$("#checkkBoxId").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr("checked")) {
        alert("Checked");
    }
    else {
        alert("Unchecked");
    }
}):
```

Comment: Use `prop` instead of `attr`.

Comment: unless your below version 1.6 @ThiefMaster as you can see in the code

Comment: `.change()` is better for this situation. User can change `checked` attribute using keybord, not a mouse.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by change the attribute @garvey it fires on click so not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkkBoxId').change(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            alert('checked');
        } else {
            alert('not checked');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Using `prop('checked')` is faster than `is(':checked')`.

Comment: -1 for not seeing what Manuel did and for downvoting every other answer except yours.

Answer (score 0):

Your code executes exactly once when the DOM is ready. So any changes will not trigger it.

Here's the proper solution:

```
$(function () {
    $('#checkkBoxId').change(function () {
        if ($("#checkkBoxId").prop('checked')) {
            alert("Checked");
        } else {
            alert("Unchecked");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah, didn't see him using an ancient version. Well.. he should update to 1.6.4.

Answer (score -2):

You have to attach the function to the checkbox's click event.

```
$("#checkkBoxId").change(function(){

          if($(this).prop("checked"))
                    {
                        alert("Checked");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Unchecked");
                    }

});
```

Comment: Use `prop` instead of `attr`. Additionally you forgot some quotes in your first line.

Comment: `.change()` is better for this situation. User can change `checked` attribute using keybord, not a mouse.